# Convert PHP Codes to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Anyone can help me to convert this code to codeigniter?

```
 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = session_id();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Did you try `php_to_codeigniter()` function ?

Comment: Ahm ok thank you very much I will do it on sunday for my free time..

Comment: Maybe on monday this post will be updated

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: @VincentDecaux if only more frameworks had that function...

Answer (score 2):

Load the session library via auto loader or manually:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then check and if needed:

```
if(! $this->session->userdata('user'))
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('user', $this->session->userdata('session_id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude.. How about sir to display multiple recaptcha? Because I have two Contact Forms.. The other contact forms is in the modal but it will now display only the recaptcha in the main page appeared. <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="####"></div>